# How to extract certain rows

Tags: r, extract, subtraction

So As you can see I have a price and Day columns below

```
 Price  Day
    2   1
    5   2
    8   3
    11  4
    14  5
    17  6
    20  7
    23  8
    26  9
    29  10
    32  11
    35  12
    38  13
    41  14
    44  15
    47  16
    50  17
    53  18
    56  19
    59  20
```

I then want the output below

```
  Difference    Day
    12  5
    15  10
    15  15
    15  20
```

So now I have the difference in prices every 5 days...it just basically subtracts the 5th day with the first day.....and then the 10th day with the 5th day etc....
I already made a code that will seperate my data into 5 day intervals...but I want the code that will let me minus the 5th with the 1st day....the 10th day with the 5th day...etc
So the code should look something like this

```
difference<-tapply(Price[,1],Day, ____________)
```

So basically Price[,1] will be my Price data.....while "Day" is the variable that I created that will let me seperate my Day data into 5 day intervals.....I'm thinking that in the blank section I could put in the function or another variable that will let me subtract the 5th day with the 1st day prices and then the 10th day and 5th day prices...etc.....you dont have to help me to seperate my Days into intervals...just how to do "difference" section....thanks guys

Comment: Something like: `vapply(seq(5,20,by=5), function(x) cbind(Diff=df[x] - df[x-5], Day=x))`

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option, assuming your `data.frame` is called "SODF":

```
within(SODF[c(1, seq(5, nrow(SODF), 5)), ], { 
  Price <- diff(c(0, Price)) 
})[-1, ]
#    Price Day
# 5     12   5
# 10    15  10
# 15    15  15
# 20    15  20
```

---

The first step is basic subsetting. According to your description and expected answer, you want the first row, and then every fifth row starting from row 5:

```
> SODF[c(1, seq(5, nrow(SODF), 5)), ]
   Price Day
1      2   1
5     14   5
10    29  10
15    44  15
20    59  20
```

From there, you can use `diff` on the "Price" column, but since `diff` will result in a vector that is one in length shorter than your input, you need to "pad" the input vector, which I did with `diff(c(0, Price))`.

```
# Correct values, but the number of rows needs to be 5
> diff(SODF[c(1, seq(5, nrow(SODF), 5)), "Price"])
[1] 12 15 15 15
```

Then, the `[-1, ]` at the end just deletes the extraneous row.

### Update

In the comments below, @geektrader points out in the comments (thanks!), an alternative to using:

```
SODF[c(1, seq(5, nrow(SODF), 5)), ]
```

as your input `data.frame`, you may consider using the following instead:

```
rbind(SODF[1,], SODF[$Day %% 5 == 0,] )
```

The difference in the two approaches is that the first approach simply subsets by *row number*, while the second approach subsets according to the *value* in the "Day" column, extracting rows where "Day" is a multiple of 5. This second approach might be useful, for instance, when there are missing rows in the dataset.

Comment: I think `rbind(df[1,], df[df$Day %% 5 == 0,] )` is better than `SODF[c(1, seq(5, nrow(SODF), 5)), ]`

Comment: @geektrader, that's a very nice alternative if you are definitely interested in every day being a multiple of 5, and not merely every fifth row. Subtle difference, but can definitely have an impact on the results.

Comment: It will also take care of cases when some values of `Day` are missing

Comment: you could also do `match(seq(5,20,by=5), df$Day)` to get the row numbers

Comment: +1 for the weighing of pros/cons of the different approaches.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for help, but I was testing the > diff(SODF[c(1, seq(5, nrow(SODF), 5)), "Price"])....for Day that goes up till 1800 and I get 'NULL' as the output....but if I try rbind function...I get only one value which is weird

Comment: @AndrewKibet, it's tough to troubleshoot with what you've given us here. See if you can create a minimal working example that replicates your problem. If possible, edit your original question to include the output of `head(dput(yourdataframe))` or at least the output of `str(yourdataframe)`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Ananda's is a nice approach (always forget about within myself).  Here's another approach:

```
dat2 <- dat[seq(0, nrow(dat), by=5), ]
data.frame(Difference=diff(c(dat[1,1], dat2[, 1])), Day=dat2[, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a **solution if you have a matrix as input**.

The subsequent function, given a matrix `m`, a column `col_id` and a numeric interval `interv`, subtracts every `interv` rows the current value in the `col_id` column of the `m` matrix with the previous value (5 rows before, same column, obiviously).

The results are stored in a new column called `diff` and appended to the end of the `m` matrix.

In short, the approach is very similar to that used by @Ananda Mahto.

So, this is the function:

```
subtract_column <- function(m, col_id, interv) {
  select <- c(1, seq(interv, nrow(m), interv))
  cbind(m[select[-1], ], diff = diff(m[select, col_id]))
}
```

Example:

```
# this emulates your data as a matrix
price_vect <- c(2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50,53,56,59)
day_vect <- 1:20
matr <- do.call(cbind, list(price = price_vect, day = day_vect))
# and this calls the function above and does the job:
# subtracts every 5 rows the current and the previous (5 rows back) value in the column `price` of matrix `matr`
subtract_column(matr, 'price', 5)
```

Output:

```
     price day diff
[1,]    14   5   12
[2,]    29  10   15
[3,]    44  15   15
[4,]    59  20   15
```