# R programming - How to find the difference between two values in specific rows

Tags: r, rows, subtraction

So As you can see I have a price and Day columns below

```
 Price  Day
    2   1
    5   2
    8   3
    11  4
    14  5
    17  6
    20  7
    23  8
    26  9
    29  10
    32  11
    35  12
    38  13
    41  14
    44  15
    47  16
    50  17
    53  18
    56  19
    59  20
```

I then want the output below

```
  Difference    Day
    12  5
    15  10
    15  15
    15  20
```

Basically I have the difference in prices every 5 days...it just basically subtracts the 5th day with the first day.....and then the 10th day with the 5th day etc.... I already made a code that will seperate my data into 5 day intervals...but I want the code that will let me minus the 5th with the 1st day prices....the 10th day with the 5th day prices...etc 
I posted a similar question a few days ago...here's the link:[How to extract certain rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286287/how-to-extract-certain-rows) ....all the answers were helpful and I sort of tried them before but they appear not to be working? Any other suggestions would be great :D
But I'm not really getting the output that I want....I have data up to 3000 days....thank u

Comment: @AndrewKibet, why are you asking the same question again? If it's not working, then you should post a comment there under the answer as to *what in particular* is not working; *not* create a new question.

Comment: Echoing @Arun, you should be able to provide a *different* example that replicates your problem. The ones there work on your sample dataset you provided here, so we really can't do much more without you sharing what you did to get a problem.

Comment: Sorry about that....but I did try to put a comment but its not appearing...my problem was when I tried the data[c(1, seq(5, nrow(data), 5)),],
diff(data[c(1, seq(5, nrow(data), 5)), "Time"].....I get a NULL result...also instead of the DAY being seperated into 5 day intervals its the prices the gets divided into 5....:O

Answer (score 1):

Create example data:

```
tmp <- structure(list(Price = c(2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 
26L, 29L, 32L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 44L, 47L, 50L, 53L, 56L, 59L), 
    Day = 1:20), .Names = c("Price", "Day"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Define index days:

```
ind <- seq(5, nrow(tmp), by=5)
```

Calculate difference for index days, match with actual day:

```
data.frame(day = tmp[ind, "Day"], diff = diff(tmp[c(1, ind), "Price"]))
```

Comment: How do u get this line without copying or pasting anything? c(2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 
26L, 29L, 32L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 44L, 47L, 50L, 53L, 56L, 59L)

Comment: @AndrewKibet Type it in?